# Is shred single pass less secure than srm?

Tags: ubuntu, benchmarking, secure-erase

i compared `shred -n 1 -v --random-source=/dev/zero file.txt` and `srm -llvzd file.txt` on 16gb file on hdd. ubuntu 14.04. both commands do single pass with zeros.

'srm' needed more than whole night while 'shred' finished in a few minutes. why? is shred less secure?

Answer (score -1):

Check the deletion process of srm , I not sure but maybe shred only makes the overwriting.
[SRM Readme](https://github.com/BlackArch/secure-delete/blob/master/README)